# MessageConverter issue while using RestTemplate with StreamingResponseBody

Tags: spring-boot, streaming, resttemplate, octetstring, http-message-converter

We have a REST API (server side) implemented using Spring Boot. This API is streaming a PDF file as `StreamingResponseBody` wrapped in `ResponseEntity` where content-type is given as `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`.

I am trying to access this API from client application with the help of `RestTemplate`. This client application is again a Spring Boot app. This client application is existing and this was supporting `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with two supportive media types so far.

`application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I followed few suggestions and tried with these items

1. Added `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` to existing
   `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`
2. Added `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` which has a default support to `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`
3. Added `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` which supporting streaming response.

But with all these suggestions I was facing the following errors. At this point of time I am not really sure if is there anything that I am missing from configuration. Team, it will be of a great help really if you can redirect me to a short examples or solutions in achieving this integration.

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [interface org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody] and content type [application/octet-stream]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

This following error was when I tried with `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` (or) `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody] and content type [application/octet-stream]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:123) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

*Updating Question with the current implementation:*
This is how resttemplate bean I am creating.

```
 @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
   final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory());
   final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
   final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new 
       MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   final List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
   mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
   //mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
   converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
   messageConverters.add(converter);
   restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
   return restTemplate;
}
```

And my API client call is

```
ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> response = reportRestTemplate.exchange(builder.buildAndExpand(uriParams).toUriString(),HttpMethod.GET,entity,StreamingResponseBody.class,uriParams);
```

Comment: Please show the code using the `RestTEmpate`. Looks like you are trying to read the results using a `StreamingResultBody` which you shouldn't do. Also why are you manually configuring the `RestTemplate` instead of using the Spring Boot default one which comes pre-configured?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated  question with existing implementation. As I mentioned earlier its an existing RestTemplate Bean using which I am trying to achieve current requirement. Also, as you mentioned if I am not supposed to read results using StreamingResultBody could you please give me an example or reference as how it should be done. Thanks for your inputs so far.

Comment: Use `byte[]` or input stream for reading. What I meant with existing `RestTemplate` is that Spring Boot provides a pre-configured one, but you are creating one yourself.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum it worked with two changes to my client. Created a new RestTemplate object and added byte[] for reading stream data.